# Carbon its parsing my date range +1 day

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have the date range

```
{"from":"2018-02-12T23:00:00.703Z","to":"2018-02-13T22:59:59.703Z"}
```

When I do a

```
$periodFrom = Carbon::parse($request->from);

$periodTo = Carbon::parse($request->to);
```

And then I want to get the number of dates between those dates I do

```
 $days = $periodTo->diffInDays($periodFrom);
```

And for some reason its giving me 0 days instead of 1 day

Edit:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$days = round($periodTo->diffInHours($periodFrom) / 24);
```

Instead of [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) you can also use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) method, it depends on what exactly result you want to get for 1.2 days, 1.8 days etc.

If you want to get 1 day instead of 0, but for all other cases you want to get just full days (8 for 8.9 for example), do this:

```
$diff = $periodTo->diffInHours($periodFrom);
$days = $diff === 0 ? 1 : $diff;
```

Comment: hmm I did that and it picked 1 day, but now when I apply front end filter to 7 days then I get 8 days instead of 7

Comment: @PrStandup you didn't tell what logic exactly you want to get. I've updated my answer. You can choose from a few options.

Comment: you are like a script on answering laravel questions! up vote.

Comment: @PrStandup this is completely new question, so you should create a new question in this case.